# Using Categories to determine whether a class has the ability to mutate an object

Tags: objective-c, oop, objective-c-category

So I have some data objects that are immutable to my view controllers, so only one class can manipulate them.  In my case, there is one Singleton object that can mutate them.  What I came up with is have the base data objects be immutable, and provide methods that allow changing of data only in categories that the Singleton class imports.  Here is an example.

---

In the view controller:

```
#import "DataStore.h"
#import "DataObject.h"
```

And then in `DataStore.m`

```
#import "DataObject.h+Mutability"
```

Which has some extra methods for mutating the objects

---

My original thought was that any class that needed to mutate data objects could do so by importing the mutability category, so it provides some level of encapsulation. But now I am rethinking because this is not how it is done with NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.  The subclasses provide a more absolute form of encapsulation. Furthermore, ideally there would be only one class that could mutate the data and would serve as the object where the other view controllers get the data they need to display. Which approach would be considered "better practice" for this general situation and why?

Comment: Everything else shouldn't even know of the existence of `DataObject`, they should just be able to ask the manager for the info they need.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Hm so what if I have a class called `User` and it contains data about a user.  If I don't know the existence of the `User` class and what it contains how would I ask for its info from the manager?